# TextView disappearing after updating using setText()

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I have 3 classes: main, Sublist and editcrap.

For now i have 2 textviews separated by a Button in the Sublist xml file; and an EditText and a Button in my editcrap xml file.

What i wanted to do was take text input from the EditText in the editcrap activity, click the Button and return it to the Sublist activity and display it in the 1st textview of the Sublist xml file. I've done this using Intents and startActivityForResult() from the Sublist actvity.

The problem:

But after receiving data bak in the Sublist activity; after the "subject1.setText(newText);" code is executed...all i see in the Sublist activity in the emulator is the Button (that was supposed to be in between the 2 TextViews) and the TextView on the right. The left TextView vanishes. No error on emulator or nothin...just the TextView vanishes. I've been tryin to get around this but no luck. Could someone tell me wat i'm overlooking? :)

my code:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch(requestCode)
    {
        case 1: if(resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK)
        {
            String newText = data.getStringExtra("thetext");
            subject1.setText(newText); 
            // this is where the textview supposed to update but 
            // instead vanishes entirely
        }
    break;
    }
}

//second activity's code:

sub1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.peditText1);    
final String theText = sub1.getText().toString();
parambutton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.parambutton1);

parambutton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(editcrap.this, Sublist.class);

            i.putExtra("thetext", theText);
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);
            finish();

        }
    });
}
```

this is how the second activity returns the input text from the EditText.

Comment: I guess the TextView would 'vanish' if the data that is being returned from the other Activity, newText, is empty. Can you show the code to pass the data back? (hopefully a call to setResult(int resultCode, Intent data))

Comment: Are you sure the extra is being set? Can you show how the second activity puts the extra data?

Comment: i've edited my question and showed the putExtra part of the code from the second activity :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), always use extra names prefixed with your package's name.

Ex: `"com.example.thetext"`

Example set result:

```
data.putExtra("com.example.thetext", yourstring);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
```

Example get result:

```
String newText = data.getStringExtra("com.example.thetext");
subject1.setText(newText);
```

To avoid mistyping the extra field name, I use string resources so I can do `getString(R.string.extra_thetext)` which stores "com.example.thetext" for me so I don't mistype it later (isn't compile-time checking great?). But you can similarly use a constant :

```
static final String THE_TEXT = "com.example.thetext";
```

Comment: tried this but its giving the same behavior...:(  could this have anything to do with the xml properties??

Comment: What is the value of `theText` on the line `i.putExtra("thetext", theText);` (set a breakpoint)?

Comment: theText contains the input from the EditText before the OnClick() method...i.e, final String theText = sub1.getText().toString();

Comment: oh crap...i solved it...i had to place the String theText = sub1.getText().toString(); inside the OnClick()....:P...man i feel stupid :P...thanks for the help though...u guys got me thinking...i just started android programming so i'm still a noob at this :P

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, my textView dissepeared after a few loop and realized that I try to assign a null value to the settext argument and it cause this problem

TLDR; check your strings if they are null or not

Answer (score -2):

You may want to use a different overload of getStringExtra.

Try using `data.getStringExtra("thetext","defaultText")`.  This will ensure SOMETHING is going to be put into the view.

Also, in case you didn't know, the first argument is the tag, not the actual text. :)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, but why was this downvoted?  Please post a solution of your own if you think this is incorrect.

Comment: The break is correctly inside the case statement and isn't in the if block or something (in the unedited question it appears he just forget the method's closing `}`). `default` would be required if the coder wanted something to happen on unhandled cases. In this case of getting an `onActivityResult` for a requestCode this app didn't request, a good response is to do nothing at all and drop it. Doing `default: break` may arguably look nice but doesn't answer this user's question. So there. :)

Comment: ninja edit for a better answer. also I upvoted your answer because it's more complete. :)

Comment: i've edited my question and showed the putExtra part of the code from the second activity :)

Comment: apparently getStringExtra() takes in only one String argument :S